# Find closed form of $T(n)=5T(n/5)+3n$, $T(1)=7$

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, closed-form

As mentioned in the title, I have to find the closed form of a recursive set:
$T(n)=5T(n/5)+3n$ $\forall n \geq 2$, $T(1)=7$.

So far I have:

$k=1$, $T(n)=5T(n/5)+3n$

$k=2$, $T(n)=5(5T(n/25)+3(n/5))+3n = 5^2T(n/25)+3n+3n$

$k=3$, $T(n)=5^2(5T(n/125)+3(n/25))+3n+3n = 5^3T(n/125)+3n+3n+3n$

$k=4$, $T(n)=5^3(5T(n/625)+3(n/125))+3n+3n+3n = 5^4T(n/625)+3n+3n+3n+3n$

EDIT: I wrote $5(5^2T(n/125)$ instead of $5^2(5T(n/125)$... Now I definitely can do the question.

Comment: Your expression for $k=3$ (and $k=4$) is wrong, and thus so is your conclusion about the end terms.  It should be $$5^2(5T(n/125)+3(n/25))+3n+3n$$The power of 5 should be outside the parentheses, but you have it inside.

Comment: I wrote it incorrectly in my post. Yes it's supposed to be what you wrote. I'll edit it.

Comment: Note that $5^{-k}T(5^k)=5^{-(k-1)}T(5^{k-1})+3$ hence $5^{-k}T(5^k)=T(1)+3k$, which you would probably translate as $T(n)=(T(1)+3\log_5n)n$.